# how can you make 2 boxes stay the same size?

Tags: html

sorry if the title is confusing, i don't know much about html. i'm wondering if there's a way you can make these two boxes stay the same size even if the content in one makes it bigger than the other? like, is there a way to make the smaller box mirror the bigger one's size, even if it has less stuff in it? html btw

attaching what i have as the coding right now; i think the reason i can't find an answer is because i don't really know how to ask the question, so i hope this makes sense to y'all. [link to the coding i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InMyq.png) thanks in advance for any help :}

Comment: please read here on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and always share your code here in a snippet and make sure it run properly in order to make it easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `min` and `max` `height` and `width` to control that, but don't forget to **manage** other things like `word wrap` and `overflow` properly.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
   
}
.box1 {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.box2 {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box1">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
 <div class="box2">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
  texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
  texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
automatic box height increase when content add in single box.
<style>
        .box-wrap {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: stretch;
        }

        .box {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="box-wrap">
        <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium provident architecto facilis quasi
            iusto
            voluptatem voluptate. Deserunt, voluptatum, ratione obcaecati nostrum corporis totam temporibus dolore
            quia
            harum impedit sit ex?
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: yellow;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium provident architecto facilis quasi
            iusto dsfjklsajf sdafjla fljsdlaf asfljlkasjdf lasfjkl asfjkl
            voluptatem
            voluptate. Deserunt, voluptatum, ratione obcaecati nostrum corporis totam temporibus
        </div>
```